# NoReverseMatch at /each_product/1/

Tags: django, django-url-reverse

I have an anchor tag in an html template as :

```
<a href="{% url 'each_product'  pk=product.id %}"> View</a>
```

In urls.py i have set up the url path as follow for this:

```
path("each_product/<int:pk>/", views.each_product, name="each_product")
```

And in view i have defined the function each_product as:

```
def each_product(request, pk):
   return render(request, "store/view_each_product.html")
```

I have template named as view_each_product.html.
Whenever i try to click view tag , it says

> "Reverse for 'each_product' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: ['each_product/(?P[0-9]+)/$']"

But , when i try to render other templates such as home page , or any other than this ! It doesn't show error.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the context also

```
def each_product(request, pk):
   product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
   return render(request, "store/view_each_product.html", {"product":product})
```